# Can we keep Pusher API keys public?

Tags: javascript, api, key

I was looking at my company site and I saw [Pusher API keys](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/getting_started/javascript) are exposed. Should it be kept public?

Comment: ... It depends on the capabilities of the API key and what might happen if it falls into a malicious person's hands ...

Comment: "exposed" how? How did you find it?